# High-voltage programming of ATTiny13 with AVRISPmkII and avrdude?

Tags: programming, attiny, avrdude

I am in the process of learning on how to program ATTiny13-20pu, and am reading this post: http://www.vk2zay.net/article/211 (archived: http://www.webcitation.org/6Imwjmidx ), which explains how to do serial communication with attiny.

Citing:

> "The fourth ADC multiplexer channel in the tiny13 requires the reset line to be dedicated as an IO pin. Setting this fuse breaks simple serial programming, so I chose to use
>   only three of the available four channels. You can alter the code if
>   you don't mind HV programming,"

To program ATTiny I am using AVRISP mkII, which I connect using 6-pin Vcc,GND,SCK,MISO,MOSI connector. External DC is 5V (GND and Vcc from avrisp are connected to GND and Vcc of that DC source, otherwise avrdude does not see the target). An example of the command on Linux:

```
avrdude -p attiny13 -c avrispmkii -P usb -U flash:w:blink.hex
```

The question is, is it possible to use HV programming in this setting or do I need something else than AVRISP? What to do with external DC source, which is now 5V and is parallel to AVRISPs Vcc/GND?

As I have too little experience in programming chips, I am trying to play safe and understand the consequences of blowing that RESET-related fuse.

If possible, please tell also if I am doing the programming in a wrong way (endangering chip or AVRISP device), or call things by wrong names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the AVRISP MkII cannot perform HV programming. The troubleshooting section of the AVRISP MkII manual ([PDF page 27](http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/AtmelStuff/avrispmkii_ug.pdf), or [item 6 on the HTML version](http://www.atmel.no/webdoc/avrispmkii/avrispmkii.troubleshooting_guide.html)) states that, if it cannot detect the target it may be because:

> The SPI interface on the target is disabled because the SPI fuse is not programmed, and/or RSTDSBL or DWEN fuse is programmed.

The resolution:

> If the ISP interface is disabled by fuse settings, one have [sic] to use another programming interface to reset these fuses. Check the device datasheet for further details on fuse settings and programming interface. STK500 can be used for High Voltage Parallel Programming, and JTAGICE mkII can be used for JTAG programming.

The AVRISP MkII has a 5V power source as a USB device, but does not incorporate a boost converter to supply the required 12V for HVSP.

Comment: There's [a guide for HVSP using the STK500](http://www.robotroom.com/Atmel-ATtiny-STK500-Programming-4.html) at robotroom.com.

Comment: `Consider that the AVRISP MkII has only 5V available as it is a USB device, hence it cannot supply the required 12V.` I object to that! There's no reason why a 5 V device couldn't use a boost converter to produce higher voltage. For example in PicKit 2, which is also USB powered, main microcontroller is used to provide high voltage for programming.

Comment: @AndrejaKo You are correct, I will rephrase that statement.